# question mark keyword in Haskell

Tags: opencv, haskell, flycapture

[I'm trying to build a wrapper for a C library.](https://github.com/skwalker/hFlyCapture/blob/master/src/System/FlyCap.hs#L185) and it has some strange syntax with question marks that I've never seen before:

```
cvLoadImage :: Capture -> IO CImage
cvLoadImage capture = do
   (Just imageRGB) <- getFrame capture
   let imageD32 = rgbToGray imageRGB
   let (CArray (nx0, ny0) (nx1, ny1) numElem values) = copyImageToFCArray imageD32
   pixelVals <- (withForeignPtr values) (peekArray numElem)
   let pixelVals' = map (fromIntegral . truncate . (*255)) pixelVals
   ptr <-( mallocArray (numElem) ::IO (Ptr Word8))
   pokeArray ptr pixelVals'
   return CImage (? ? ? pixelVals' ? ? ? ?) -- this is the line I'm confounded by
```

It's causing a syntax error when I compile:

```
src/System/FlyCap.hs:185:21: parse error on input ‘?’
```

Looking up "?" on Hoogle finds something about ['implicit parameters'](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Implicit_parameters) but that doesn't seem to be related. I tried replacing the mysterious question marks with type holes:

```
 return CImage (_ _ _ pixelVals' _ _ _ _)
```

That gave me a much bigger error:

```
src/System/FlyCap.hs:186:4:
    Couldn't match type ‘IO CImage’
                  with ‘CUInt
                        -> CUInt
                        -> CUInt
                        -> Ptr CUChar
                        -> CUInt
                        -> CInt
                        -> CInt
                        -> Ptr ()
                        -> CImage’
    Expected type: t6 -> IO CImage
      Actual type: t6
                   -> CUInt
                   -> CUInt
                   -> CUInt
                   -> Ptr CUChar
                   -> CUInt
                   -> CInt
                   -> CInt
                   -> Ptr ()
                   -> CImage
    The function ‘return’ is applied to two arguments,
    but its type ‘(CUInt
                   -> CUInt
                   -> CUInt
                   -> Ptr CUChar
                   -> CUInt
                   -> CInt
                   -> CInt
                   -> Ptr ()
                   -> CImage)
                  -> t6
                  -> CUInt
                  -> CUInt
                  -> CUInt
                  -> Ptr CUChar
                  -> CUInt
                  -> CInt
                  -> CInt
                  -> Ptr ()
                  -> CImage’
    has only 10
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: return CImage (_ _ _ pixelVals' _ _ _ _)
    In the expression:
      do { (Just imageRGB) <- getFrame capture;
           let imageD32 = rgbToGray imageRGB;
           let (CArray (nx0, ny0) (nx1, ny1) numElem values)
                 = copyImageToFCArray imageD32;
           pixelVals <- (withForeignPtr values) (peekArray numElem);
           .... }
```

I'm really not sure of how to proceed. Any tips?

UPDATE: I found the [original repo, which seems to have fixed this](https://github.com/imalsogreg/flycap), but I still wonder what the question marks are?

Comment: Are you sure they are not just something that the author forgot to fill in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?` is not a syntax, its a valid operator in haskell. But here its just a "some magic here" thing.

The authors, as marked above, just forgot to replace it with some expression involving the `pixelVals'`. Most probably, it should be the construction of `CImage` parameter(s?) out of that pixel values.

Ghc's parser will give `parse error` on any two sequental tokens made of operator symbols (except for `-`) - because of that it failed after the second question mark.